# Why is my Python PyAutoGUI / Image grab script slow?

Tags: python, pyautogui

So I am making an automated clicker, I want to ask what can I do to optimise my code to make it faster, it is currently working however it recognises the pixel colour and then clicks too slow. I have tried using space it seems just the same.

Would it be faster if instead of a box it was just a pixel? Also, is there an alternative to a.sum(), instead of calculating the total would it be faster to use the original value.

The aim of the project is to find a pixel/box on the screen, when the colour value changes to a certain color (white or in grey range) it would then click a button.

```py
from pyautogui import *
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import ImageOps
import pyautogui

import time
import keyboard
import random
from numpy import*
import os

emark = (1440, 1026) 
pyautogui.click(x=1063, y=544)

def image_grab():
    box = (emark[0]+1,emark[1],emark[0]+11,emark[1]+2)
    image = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    grayImage = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
    a = array(grayImage.getcolors())
    return a.sum()

def clickButton():
    #pyautogui.press('space') 
    pyautogui.click(x=1160, y=600)
 
while True:
    image_grab()
    if 1000 <= image_grab() <= 1700:
        clickButton()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do all that color conversion and numpy array stuff.  Just grab one pixel, save it's color value, then grab a new pixel, and test for equality.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui

emark = ( 1440, 1026 )
pyautogui .click( x=1063, y=544 )

pixel = ( emark[0]-1, emark[1]-1, emark[0]+1, emark[1]+1 )
original_pixel_color = ImageGrab .grab( pixel ) .getpixel( (0,0) )
##  print( original_pixel_color )

def image_grab():
    new_pixel_color = ImageGrab .grab( pixel ) .getpixel( (0,0) )
    return new_pixel_color == original_pixel_color

def clickButton():
    ##  print('yup')
    pyautogui .click( x=1160, y=600 )

while True:
    if not image_grab():
        clickButton()
        ##  I don't know if pyautogui has a built in pause function,  
        ##  or repeat delay, but you probably want a time.sleep(1)
        ##  or similar here, so it doesn't rapid-fire autoclick
        ##  500 times in a row, once that pixel changes color.
```

---

Not needed for you script, but how I figured `getpixel()` is the fastest, of those ImageGrab methods, that return comparable color data.

```
import timeit
loops = 99999

print( 'tobytes()', timeit .timeit( lambda : original_pixel_color .tobytes(), number=loops ) )
print( 'getcolors()', timeit .timeit( lambda : original_pixel_color .getcolors(), number=loops ) )
print( 'getpixel()', timeit .timeit( lambda : original_pixel_color .getpixel( (0,0) ), number=loops ) )
```

---

**Edit:**  `ImageGrab .grab( pixel )` grabs a screen rectangle, according to the size you give it.

```
( emark[0] -1, emark[1] -1,  emark[0] +1, emark[1] +1 )  ##  x, y, w, h
```

Due to limitations in PIL, the minimum coordinate space is 2x2, *hence* the `emark -1, emark +1`.
*I think that's right*, but I'm going on recollections from years ago here.  They might say the definitive pixel location here on **SO** somewhere, but you could try

```
( emark[0], emark[1],  emark[0] +2, emark[1] +2 )
```

if off by one.  Either way, it really only grabs one pixel.

`.getpixel( (0,0) )` returns the **RGB value** of that pixel, as a tuple.
so yea, instead of snapping a pixel to begin with, you could just use your own value there.

```
original_pixel_color = ( 240, 240, 240 ) 

def brighter_than():
    new_pixel_color = ImageGrab .grab( pixel ) .getpixel( (0,0) )
    r = new_pixel_color[0] >= original_pixel_color[0]
    g = new_pixel_color[1] >= original_pixel_color[1]
    b = new_pixel_color[2] >= original_pixel_color[2]
    return  r and g and b

while True:
    if not brighter_than():
        clickButton()
```

Also, at the beginning, after your import:

> Fail-Safes
> Set up a 2.5 second pause after each PyAutoGUI call:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui .PAUSE = 2.5
```

https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

---

**Post postcript:**  Well in some of those cases they're saving/displaying an image, not just getting the color, so a lot of that can be stripped out.  Used `sp` because it was easier to figure out at the time and was quick enough for what I was doing.

```
import subprocess as sp

xx, yy = 640, 480
ww, hh = 1, 1
pixel_location = f'{xx},{yy},{ww},{hh}'
cmd = [ 'scrot', 'temp.tiff', '--autoselect', pixel_location, '--silent' ]

sp .Popen( cmd )
```

I know scrot is a Linux command, but it would be a similar routine with screenshot in OSX, you'd just need to tweak the args to whatever it's expecting.  I only say this because it worked for me, however calling an extra BASH process would create a tiny amount of overhead and miliseconds of lag, so you likely want to *go with a direct call to the library instead...*

---

Think *that answer* is in Tiger's response, and n4p strips a lot of it out, so that's promising;  but those function calls are out of my scope of knowledge as well, so making educated guesses at this point.  Have no way of testing it here, so you'd have to try and see.  Trying to skip numpy and pillow if at all possible, by using a quick struct unpack - that should be the fastest.

```
import struct
import pyautogui
import Quartz.CoreGraphics as CG

pyautogui .PAUSE = 2.5
xx, yy = 500, 500
ww, hh = 1, 1
region = CG .CGRectMake( xx, yy, ww, hh )

orig = ( 240, 240, 240 ) 

def brighter_than():  ##  think these properties are right...
    pixel = CG .CGWindowListCreateImage( region, CG .kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, CG .kCGNullWindowID, CG .kCGWindowImageDefault )

    data = CG .CGDataProviderCopyData( CG .CGImageGetDataProvider( pixel ) )
    ##  backwards from RGBA, Mac stores pixels as BGRA instead
    b, g, r, a = struct .unpack_from( 'BBBB', data )  ##  BBBB = 4 Bytes

    return r >= orig[0] and g >= orig[1] and b >= orig[2]

while True:
    if brighter_than():
        clickButton()
```

Some of that info comes from dbr's [blog writeup](http://neverfear.org/blog/view/156/OS_X_Screen_capture_from_Python_PyObjC) .  And `CGRectMake()` comes from [Converting CGImage to python image (pil/opencv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938654/converting-cgimage-to-python-image-pil-opencv) .  Everybody else was using `region = CG.CGRectInfinite` which likely grabs the *entire screen* instead of one pixel.

Comment: Just some questions so I can learn and understand, so "original_pixel_color" function is to grab the pixel coordinates, and it doesn't define a colour? Not sure what the difference of .grab( pixel ) and .getpixel( (0,0) ). Then def image_grab is comparing the original pixel color and the new pixel color, if it changes the clickButton function initiates. How can I set it so if the colour white or grey value range e.g (240-255), is the color of that pixel it will initiate the click, instead of color comparison? Overall, thank you for such a detailed answer and the extra result test you did.

Comment: Hello, this is perfect I have managed to combine them so it's working, I have set the original pixel to 250,250,205 and anything above that now activates the click, i've changed the 'if not' to 'if' brighter than.

The only problem now is it is still clicking slow, pretty much the same as my original code. Im thinking it's either the pixel recognition to click is too slow? or pyauto.click is too slow, or possibly my hardware affects it. I saw a video that uses win32 api to click as it's 10x faster but i'm on MAC OS, any recommendation for the equivalent?

Comment: oh yea yer right, that should be an `if`.  I'll change it here in a sec.  Yeah, I've seen people have better results using `ctypes`.  It calls a C library instead of processing in Python.  I'd have to think for a minute where that was.  The other day someone was asking about automating with it.  They've got examples on GitHub.  Let me grab a cup of tea, then I'll hunt for a Mac version.

Comment: Have you heard of Pynput and Apple Script wrapped in Python, I had a look at some of the examples seem quite heavy in lines. I'm not sure how to determine what makes it faster or slower?

Comment: It's possible PIL is really slow.  As I recall it actually grabs entire screenbuffer, then crops out the specific pixel you're looking for.  The only benefit there is the color conversion being faster on one pixel than many.  Did something in Linux a dozen years ago, think that was more of a limiting factor than click delay.  You could do a similar `timeit()` call w/ a couple screenshots vs clicks, print times they return.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099411/os-x-and-ctypes-how-to-retrieve-raw-pixels-from-cgdataprovidercopydata -- hmm --https://stackoverflow.com/a/11048135/3342050

Comment: Think I ended up doing a `subprocess.pcall()` to scrot, but I don't remember the format specified, *XxY-W-H* ??.  on Mac they call it screencapture instead  https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html  What n4p says here reiterates what Tiger mentioned in that other post, that calling quartz/cocoa is faster than trying to do it strictly through Python  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978846/python-get-screen-pixel-value-in-os-x though dropping that pixel straight into a numpy array would be faster than trying to `reshape()` it  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68109395/3342050

Comment: This is really detailed, I do recall coming across quartz/cocoa, I will have a look into the autopy library too The deep info in those posts are far from my understanding and knowledge. I apologise if there is any misunderstanding but my programming is fairly just a miniscule. I will continue to look at those slowly and try to understand after some sleep, thanks I really appreciate your help and guidance.

Comment: I have tried the top script (Scrot?), I think it's supposed to be' import subprocess as sp' instead of subrocess. The problem I ran into was sp .pcall( cmd ), wasn't sure how to use this. Anyway, I tried the second script, I combined it with the previous script functions and it's perfectly working fast, much faster. Your script to skip numpy and pillow, by using a quick struct unpack works much better :). I will continue to make some improvements by adding some other functions from what I learned. I wish I could give you the reputation you deserve but it seems mine is too low, thanks!

Comment: yea right again, typos were made.  Was thinking of subprocess's `Popen` and `call` and Lua's `pcall` which is a *protected function call* instead of an external call, and mixed them.  Should'a tried running it before posting.  Glad ya got it running tho.